# SVG.js not drawing svg into container (Polymer)

Tags: polygon, svg.js

I've installed svg.js using NPM and imported the module into my custom element file via `import "svg.js";`,

```
import "svg.js";

class MyView2 extends PolymerElement {
  static get template() {
    return html`

      <div id="drawing"></div>

    `;
  }

  connectedCallback() {
    super.ready();
    var draw = SVG("drawing").size(300, 300);
    var rect = draw.rect(100, 100).attr({ fill: "#f06" });
  }
}
```

This *should* insert an SVG inside of the `div`, but is it's throwing this error in the console instead:

```
svg.js:3060 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of null
    at new create (svg.js:3060)
    at globalRef.SVG (svg.js:33)
    at HTMLElement.connectedCallback (my-view2.js:42)
    at my-view2.js:50
```

I'm fairly new to Polymer so not sure if i'm missing something obvious.

Comment: can you check if there is indeed a div with the correct id in the document right before you call SVG?

Answer (score 0):

Your component has a Shadow Dom so SVG can't find it. Please try this:

```
let node = this.shadowRoot.querySelector('drawing');
let draw = SVG.adopt(node);
let rect = draw.rect(100, 100).attr({ fill: "#f06" });
```